# SocketException: Connection refused using EasyNetQ ManagementClient

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, socketexception, easynetq, econnrefused

I have `RabbitMQ` with management console installed on my machine. Web interface is working on
http://localhost:15672

When I try to access Rabbit via code, I'm getting an exception:

```
var mcGuest = new ManagementClient("http://localhost", "guest", "guest", 15672);
var vhost = mcGuest.GetVhost("/");
```

> {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it [::1]:15672"}

(source code for Management Client at https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ.Management.Client)

I'm running Visual Studio as Administrator, getting following output when running `netstat -anb`:

```
Line 35:   TCP    0.0.0.0:5672           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Line 37:   TCP    0.0.0.0:15672          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Line 39:   TCP    0.0.0.0:25672          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Line 200:   TCP    127.0.0.1:15672        127.0.0.1:18577        ESTABLISHED
Line 212:   TCP    127.0.0.1:18577        127.0.0.1:15672        ESTABLISHED
Line 484:   TCP    [::]:5672              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is with IPv6. Could be related to my environment.

When running `EasyNetQ` api on Debug, IPv6 is used and I'm getting the error. When running on Release, IPv4 is used and sockets works.

The immediate solution is to use

```
new ManagementClient("http://127.0.0.1", "guest", "guest", 15672);
```

Though I still don't know why `localhost` and IPv6 wouldn't work. You can see IPv6 is used by the exception details - [`[::1]` which stands for localhost IP in v6](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/11053).